# Как удалить корневой элемент из QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qt5

В слоте обрабатываю удаление элементов дерева. Все элементы удаляются, кроме последнего (корневого).

```
void TreeModel::slotDelete()
{
 QStandardItem *curItem = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex());
 QStandardItem *curParent = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex())->parent();

 if(!curItem || !curParent) return;

 curParent->removeRow(curItem->row());
}
```

Почему при попытке удалении последнего элемента `curParent` равен `0x0`?

**Уточнение**: Дерево я строю, используя корневой элемент `invisibleRootItem()`.

Подскажите, как удалить последний (корневой) элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного покопавшись в документации, я сам нашел решение.

```
void TreeModel::slotDelete()
{
 QStandardItem *curItem = itemFromIndex(_tvMainTree->currentIndex());
 if(!curItem) return;

 QStandardItem *curParent = curItem->parent();
 if(!curParent)
 {
  invisibleRootItem()->removeRow(curItem->row());
  return;
 }

 curParent->removeRow(curItem->row());
}
```